# Not able to use JPA annotation @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent class Contact which has one to one relationship with ContactType.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private ContactType contactType;
```

I am trying to create a new contact using ContactRepository.save() which extends JPARepository. I am getting the following error.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint type. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ContactType

If I change the contact type declaration to below:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private ContactType contactType;
```

I get the following error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Code used to create a contact (It just calls JPARepository.save()):

```
contactsRepository.save(contact);
```

How to use merge and persist the data at the same time.

Comment: How many contact types are there? Please post the code for Contact Type?

Comment: Contact Type is just a simple class which points to Type table. It can have as many row values as being inserted.

Comment: and what is the primary key? you mean as many rows as there there are Contacts?

Comment: The primary Key is type string. It should insert a new row to Type table if the user enters new type Ex:"Type2" when creating a new contact. If the user enters already existing type then it should to insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments mentioned:

> The primary Key is type string. I want to insert a new row to type if
>   the user enters new type Ex:"Type2" when creating a new contact. If
>   the user enters already existing type then I dont want to insert a new
>   row.

This makes sense then why you're getting a Cannot insert duplicate key error.

The reality is there is not a one to one relationship between Contact and Contact Type as there is not one contact type for every contact. As you said, contact types are reused. What you should be doing is using a many to one between Contact and Contact Type as one contact can have only one Contact Type but one Contact Type can apply to more than one Contact. Iow, the same Contact Type can be one more than one Contact.

So you make it a many to one and then before you save you'll need to look up the Contact Type matching the given one and insert that one if it exists, if not, populate it and let the cascade save the new Contact Type.

Comment: A given contact can have only one type. It cant have multiple values associated to it. For example: Type table has 2 rows type1 and type2. Contact1 can have only one of these either type1 or type2. If the user enters type3 then it should create a new row type3.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `contactsRepository.save(contact)` with:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private ContactType contactType;
```

raises exception because the persistence context cascades the `persist` operation and sees `contactType` as `transient` with primary key set, ready to be persisted. A row with the same PK already exists, hence the error.

The second case:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private ContactType contactType;
```

The operation is `persist` (not `merge`) therefore not cascaded. The persistent context sees `contactType` as `transient` and cannot go further with the `persist` because one of the dependencies is in `transient` state.

**Solution**

Get rid of cascade:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private ContactType contactType;
```

Before calling `contactsRepository.save(contact);` make sure the `contactType` is in managed state. You can do it this way:

```
contact.setContactType( entityManager.getReference(ContactType.class, contactType.getId()));
```

Make sure you replace `getId()` with the primary key getter.

Merging `contactType` into the persistence context with `contact.setContactType(contactTypeRepository.merge(contactType));` is also valid.

Comment: I am able to add the row but the foreign key id in the child table (Contc_id) is entered as Null. Its not inputting the newly generated contact ID.